# How can I label a line in NX Open C#?

Tags: c#, .net, label, nomachine-nx, nxopen

How would I label these lines using coding?

I have already figured out how to identify and count up how many lines exist using this code:

```cs
using NXOpen;

using System;

public class FailedRegionCounting
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Session theSession=Session.GetSession();
        Part workpart=theSession.Parts.Work;
 
        int numLine = 0;

        foreach (NXOpen.Curve tempFeat in workpart.Curves)

        {
            string name = tempFeat.Name;
            string a = "Line";           

            if (name.Contains(a))
            {
                numLine = numLine + 1;
            }    
        }
        Guide.InfoWriteLine("This analysis has " + numLine + " of Lines.");
    }
}
```

However, I would like to learn how I would label these lines on NX.

This is somewhat of a result I desire:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use PMI notes for achieving this.
2. If you want to display temporary names, then there are some functions where you can create temporary Names for the curves.

   ```
    UFObj.DispProps props = new UFObj.DispProps();
    props.color = 186;
    double[] loc = {rcpPoint.X+5, rcpPoint.Y+5, rcpPoint.Z+5};
    theUFSession.Disp.DisplayTemporaryText(
        Tag.Null, UFDisp.ViewType.UseWorkView,
        inx.ToString(), loc, UFDisp.TextRef.Middlecenter, ref props, 10.0, 1);
   ```